# get values from input fields with the same name propely formated

Tags: jquery, input

I have some Input fields with the same name as arrays in a loop.

Something like :

```
<input name="vehicle[$i][amount]" ...> // $i = 1
<input name="vehicle[$i][name]" ...>

<input name="vehicle[$i][amount]" ...> // $i = 1
<input name="vehicle[$i][name]" ...>

<input name="vehicle[$i][amount]" ...> // $i = 1
<input name="vehicle[$i][name]" ...>
```

Now I want to get the values of all inputs with the name "vehicle"

The output I want should be something like:

```
[0] => 'amount' => (for example) 5
       'name' => BMW
[1] => 'amount' => (for example) 15
       'name' => Audi
```

and so on.

How do I get this? I've tried multiple things out.

Something like:

```
    var vehicle;
    $('input[name="product"]').each(function () {
        vehicle.push($(this).val());
    });
```

But this and similar solutions I've tried haven't worked for me.

Thanks four your help and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: The amount should be the `value` of your input, like this `<input name="vehicle[$i][name]" value="vehicle[$i][amount]">`

Comment: Are you creating your input with PHP?

Comment: yes I create it with PHP. And the name and the amount are two different things.

It's not like there is a existing name that I want to give a amount value.

I want to create a new name with a new value. 

I did a mistake in my question. All those input field have the same $i value. There are all "1" in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the input with this:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    print('<div class="vehicle">');
    print('<input name="amount">');
    print('<input name="name">');
    print('</div>');
}
?>
```

And then...

```js
var vehicle = [];
$('div.vehicle').each(function () {
  var name = $(this).children('input[name="name"]').val();
  var amount = $(this).children('input[name="amount"]').val();
  vehicle.push({ name: name, amount: amount });
});

console.log(vehicle);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vehicle">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="BMW">
  <input type="number" name="amount" value="5">
</div>
<div class="vehicle">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Audi">
  <input type="number" name="amount" value="3">
</div>
<div class="vehicle">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Ford">
  <input type="number" name="amount" value="6">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all vehicle by name contain your string with selector `*`:

```
var vehicle = [];
$('input[name*="Audi"]').each(function () {
    vehicle.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This way gave me the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined --- and another thing, you mean 'input[name*="vehicle"]' -- right?

Comment: Yes right! create your variable vehicle as array. Please try my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this:

<input name="titles[]">
<input name="titles[]">
​<button>submit</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

With this jQuery

// click handler
function onClick(event) {
  var titles = $('input[name^=titles]').map(function(idx, elem) {
    return $(elem).val();
  }).get();

  console.log(titles);
  event.preventDefault();
}

// attach button click listener on dom ready
$(function() {
  $('button').click(onClick);
});
```

Comment: well that works only the half way. there are 6 fields. 

Now it's giving me the values back in a simple array: Like this:

["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

But I want it like this: [0] = amount => "1", price => '2' 
[1] = amount => "3", price => '4'

Comment: @dwdawdawdaw  If you want this type of result use filter() method in javascript

Comment: can you give me a example how to filter it in this code snippet? The jquery doc. only gives me css solutions so I'm a little bit confused about that

Comment: Refer this url https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter   $('input[name^=titles]').filter()